# fastcgi-mono-server4 debugging on nginx, is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, mono, nginx

A lot of information is available on how to set debug using xsp server for local development purposes, just an [example](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_ASP.NET) from the official mono website:

> I would like line numbers in my stack traces
>
> By default xsp and xsp2 run in "release" mode, which means that no
>   debugging information is generated at runtime. If you want line
>   numbers in your stack traces, you must pass the --debug option to
>   Mono, this is done by invoking xsp or xsp2 with the MONO_OPTIONS
>   environment variable, like this:
>
> ```
> $ MONO_OPTIONS=--debug xsp
> Listening on port: 8080 (non-secure)
> Listening on address: 0.0.0.0
> Root directory: /tmp/us
> Hit Return to stop the server.
> ```
>
> If you are running mod_mono with Apache, you must use the MonoDebug
>   directive in your configuration file, like this:
>
> ```
> MonoDebug true
> ```

Is it possible on nginx?

Answer (score 4):

I've just ran into the same problem myself and was able to fix it :)

The `MONO_OPTIONS` environment variable can hold additional parameters that are passed to the mono executable. So if you do:

```
export MONO_OPTIONS="--debug"
fastcgi-mono-server-4 /applications="/:/srv/www/htdocs/mywebapp" /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000
```

You should get debug information (linenumber and files) upon error, provided of course you also deployed the *.mdb files which hold the debug information.

I personally use a modified verison of [the init script found here](http://yojimbo87.github.com/2010/03/14/mono-startup-script.html) which is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          monoserve.sh
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $syslog $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $syslog $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start fastcgi mono server with hosts
### END INIT INFO

source /etc/mono-addon-env
NAME=monoserver
DESC=monoserver

MONO_OPTIONS="--debug"
MONOSERVER=$(which fastcgi-mono-server4)
MONOSERVER_PID=$(ps auxf | grep fastcgi-mono-server4.exe | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')

WEBAPPS="/:/srv/www/htdocs/mywebapp/"

case "$1" in
        start)
                if [ -z "${MONOSERVER_PID}" ]; then
                        echo "starting mono server"
                        ${MONOSERVER} /applications=${WEBAPPS} /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 &
                        echo "mono server started"
                else
                        echo ${WEBAPPS}
                        echo "mono server is running"
                fi
        ;;
        stop)
                if [ -n "${MONOSERVER_PID}" ]; then
                        kill ${MONOSERVER_PID}
                        echo "mono server stopped"
                else
                        echo "mono server is not running"
                fi
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

But **PAY ATTENTION**: In case you use that init script to start up the fastcgi daemon, DO NOT USE any init tools like "service monoserve start" (RHEL/CentOS) or "rcMonoserve start". For me this will not work, I suspect the init system will spawn another process with different environment variables. To be safe, only call the script directly, i.e.
    /etc/init.d/monoserve start
and put in in /etc/rc.local or such.

Comment: I'm going to test this. Great.

Comment: this scripts mainly have two problem in RHEL/Centos  1. is not a standard RHEL init scripts 2. enviroment variables: you can simply source you user profile in this scripts firtst to simply sovle this issue